# show like a block of three cells have to remove cellspacing

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]http://jsbin.com/uzojax/11/edit

```
<table cellspacing="1" width="50%" bgcolor="#cccccc" width="50%">
     <tr class="csstextheader">
     <td>   
     </td>
     <td>Class  
     </td>
     <td>Numbers
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr class="csstablelisttd">
     <td> 1  
     </td>
     <td>2  
     </td>
     <td>3
     </td>
     </tr>
      <tr class="csstablelisttd">
     <td>  4
     </td>
     <td class='csstdred' > 
     </td>
     <td> 6  
     </td>
     </tr>   
      <tr class="csstablelisttd">
     <td >  7 
     </td>
     <td class='csstdred'>  8
     </td>
    <td>   9
     </td>
     </tr>  
      <tr class="csstablelisttd">
     <td> 10
     </td>
     <td class='csstdred'>
     </td>
    <td>12
    </td>
     </tr>      
   </table>
```

I have to remove border of cells having class csstdred and have to show like a block of three cells without rowspan.

Comment: Use `border-collapse: collapse;` for the `table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use this CSS:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ogusaq/1/edit

---

#### Update #1:

If you want the other borders:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.csstdred {border-color: #f00;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/iwenuw/1/edit

#### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

---

#### Update #2:

If you want only one `table` to get affected, give the table a class `.redborder`:

```
table.redborder {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.redborder td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
table.redborder .csstdred {border-color: #f00;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ujabav/1/edit

---

#### Update #3:

When the `.csstdred` is clicked, then it should change to blue colour. That can be done only using JavaScript. So, here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".csstdred").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Add this CSS for the active state:

```
table.redborder {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.redborder td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
table.redborder .csstdred {border-color: #f00;}
table.redborder .csstdred.active {border-color: #00f; border-width: 2px 1px 1px 2px; border-collapse: separate;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ihejep/1/edit

---

#### Update #4

```
table.redborder {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.redborder td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
table.redborder .csstdred {border-color: #f00;}
table.redborder .csstdred div {border: 1px solid #f00;}
table.redborder .csstdred.active div {border: 1px solid #00f;}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".csstdred").wrapInner("<div>").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/abekup/1/edit

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/abekup/5/edit (Updated)

Comment: Praveen i get border on all td of whole page

Comment: Give the table a class and target the style to that table alone. Is it possible? See my updated answer.

Comment: praveen ur answer is pefect but i have one more critical problem for selection of cells:(

Comment: @lax What is it? What problem are you facing?

Comment: ping me the jsbin link here... make sure you click on clone, so that it generates a new url and you don't give the old one. `:)`

Comment: see praveen when i click on 8 i have make block  8 border blue using another css...

Comment: @lax You can do that only using JavaScript. What you are trying to do is an event triggering.

Comment: in above jsbin i m calculating rowindex and colindex and add class according to that in css class i m specifying only border but border not shows to whole block

Comment: praven i have make whole block border blue.ONly bock no cells under it

Comment: Right, it makes only that cell's border blue.

Comment: praveen see in quetion image like that border i have to make on click of cell

Comment: In case of tables, border is a problem.

Comment: so what would be the solution

Comment: means i have to change whole page ..:(

Comment: Yeah. Or can you think of changing background color, which is very easy?

Comment: i want border praveen...changing div is so complicated because i have done travesing code

Comment: Okay. I got the solution for you. Updating it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

no modification in CSS.. just changed html

plz check on this http://jsbin.com/uzojax/34/

Answer (score 0):

Use can change the tb to div for particular place.

```
    <td rowspan="3" class="csstdred">
    <div><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p></div>
    </td>
```